# Is a varistor basically two diodes in series, with opposite polarities?

Tags: varistor

The typical curve for current vs voltage for a varistor:

[image]

looks a lot like the 2 reverse voltage regions of a normal diode:

[image]

Is this equivalent the following, and if not, why not?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMqFXj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Varistor isn't *two* diodes in series, it's a chaotic mesh of thousands of little diodes in all sorts of orientations.

Courtesy of wikipedia:

> The most common type of varistor is the metal-oxide varistor (MOV). This type contains a ceramic mass of zinc oxide grains, in a matrix of other metal oxides (such as small amounts of bismuth, cobalt, manganese) sandwiched between two metal plates (the electrodes). The boundary between each grain and its neighbour forms a diode junction, which allows current to flow in only one direction. The mass of randomly oriented grains is electrically equivalent to a network of back-to-back diode pairs, each pair in parallel with many other pairs

Answer (score -1):

A reasonable model might be more like two zener diodes with a relatively high resistor in series.

Comment: I like to two zeners, but don't understand the high resistor.

Comment: My thinking was that the knees of a varister is much less sharp than that of a zener.